# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am having problems with `oci_connect()` in PHP. I can't connect with an Oracle Database, after I had installed the `Oracle InstantClient(32 Bit)` and copied the required *.dll's in the `apache/bin/` and `xampp/php` folders.

I get this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\OracleTest\connect.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\OracleTest\connect.php on line 9.

There is also the Problem that I am unable to load the dynamic libraries:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - The specified module could not
>   be found. in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll' - The specified module could not
>   be found. in Unknown on line 0

My Code is this:

```
$oc_conn = oci_connect('127.0.0.1/XE','****', '****');
    if($oc_conn)
    {
        echo "Success!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
```

I am struggling on that Problem for over 3 weeks..I really need help, thank you in advance.

Comment: I have 'oci.dll' in Apache bin folder. And  'extension=php_oci8_12c.dll' in php.ini

Comment: I have also these the oci.dll in the apache/bin folder and removed the semicolon ind php.ini

Answer (score 1):

The "Call to undefined function oci_connect()" seems to be a secondary error resulting from a root cause error.  The root cause error, as the error message says, seems to be that PHP cannot find the file named `C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll`.  PHP will get this file name from the `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll` statement in your php.ini.  It also seems that your php.ini has defined `C:\xampp\php\ext\` as the place where extension code should be located.

FIX:  Make sure the .dll is in `C:\xampp\php\ext\`, not just `apache/bin`.  Also, make sure the name of the .dll is `php_oci8_11g.dll`, not `oci.dll`.

Successfully loading a dynamic library / extension will (usually) make new functions and classes available to your PHP code.  Once you've got `php_oci8_11g.dll` loaded, you'll probably find that the `oci_connect()` error is fixed too.

Comment: The .dll files are in both folders, and I have also the needed 11g.dll file, but its still not working.

Comment: Is "11g.dll" the exact name of the file you have?  Or are you just being brief?

Comment: No its the php_oci8_11g.dll, but I called it 11g.dll

Comment: So, are you saying this (exactly named) file exists: "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll" ???  If yes, then you should not be getting the error message saying it could not be found.

Comment: Yes it is the exact name like in the php.ini file. That's the problem, it should work, but it dose not.

Comment: Both file name (as in php.ini) AND file path ("c:\xampp\php\ext\")?!?!?!?  If yes, then I have no idea why you are getting a "could not be found" error message.

Comment: What is the setting of `extension_dir` in your php.ini file?

Comment: Yes, its everywhere the same, I am also drivers for MySQL and MicrosoftSQL and these are working fine.

Comment: what do you mean with setting?

Comment: Also, just occurred to me.  Are you running 64-bit PHP and using a 32-bit oci .dll, or vice versa?  This might be a problem too.